# Android: How to change an ImageView in a ListView item onClick corresponding to an SQLiteDatabase entry?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, android-imageview, simplecursoradapter

**What I have:**

I have an `Activity` with a `ListView`. The `layout` for the `ListView` item is custom and contains an `ImageView` and several `TextViews`. I populate the `ListView` with data from an `SQLiteDatabase` using a standard `SimpleCursorAdapter` (no customization in the adapter yet). Each `ListView` item represents a certain object whose attributes are saved in one database row. All `TextViews` get filled correctly with the data from the according database columns, no problem with that.

**What I want:**

By clicking on the `ImageView` I want to change the `image` AND a certain attribute of my object in the database. It's something like an on/off with changing an `image` in my `ListView` item and switching between 0 and 1 in my database at the according column.

**My question:**

Where do I have to implement the `OnClickListener`? How do I handle convert views (because there can be more than 12 ListView items and I want each item to show the right image depending on the entry in the according database column)? I did something similar with and `ArrayAdapter` and a simpler model following this tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection_data). But it's not made for interaction with an `SQLiteDatabase`. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

Here is my adapter code (now with some customization):

```
public class IOIOSensorCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
static class ViewHolder
{
ImageView iv;
}

private Context ctx;
private Cursor cursor;
private IodDatabaseManager dbm;

public IOIOSensorCursorAdapter(Context _context, int _layout,
    Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to, int _flags)
{
super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to, _flags);
ctx = _context;
cursor = _cursor;
dbm = new IodDatabaseManager(_context);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int _position, View _convertView,
    ViewGroup _parent)
{
ViewHolder holder = null;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// There is no view at this position, we create a new one. In this case
// by inflating an xml layout.
if (_convertView == null)
{
    _convertView = inflater
        .inflate(R.layout.listview_item_sensor, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.iv = (ImageView) _convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.stateImageView);
    _convertView.setTag(holder);
}
// We recycle a View that already exists.
else
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) _convertView.getTag();
}

holder.iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view)
    {
    // Here I should react on the click and change the database
    // entry and the image

    cursor.moveToPosition(_position);

    Log.d("onClick: position", "" + _position);

    int sensorID = cursor.getInt(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.SENSOR_ID));

    Log.d("onClick: sensorID", "" + sensorID);

    int state = cursor.getInt(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.STATE));

    Log.d("onClick: state", "" + state);

    if (state == 0)
    {
        dbm.updateSensorState(sensorID, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        dbm.updateSensorState(sensorID, 0);
    }

    cursor = dbm.getIOIOSensorsCursor();
    }
});

int state = cursor.getInt(cursor
    .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.STATE));

if (state == 0)
{
    holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.av_play_over_video);
}
else
{
    holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.av_pause_over_video);
}

return _convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post what you did till now,or in which area you are having problem

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm allowed to do that right now due to legal reasons. I'd be grateful for some general ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I have to answer my own question. I finally solved it myself. Very important was to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the onCLickListener and `cursor.moveToPosition(_position)` below it. Before that I got some weird behavior after clicking on the `ImageView`. Now everything works as it should. Hope this might help some of you guys.

Here is my code:

```
public class IOIOSensorCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    static class ViewHolder
    {
    ImageView iv;
    }

    private Context ctx;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private IodDatabaseManager dbm;

    public IOIOSensorCursorAdapter(Context _context, int _layout,
        Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to, int _flags)
    {
    super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to, _flags);
    ctx = _context;
    cursor = _cursor;
    dbm = new IodDatabaseManager(_context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int _position, View _convertView,
        ViewGroup _parent)
    {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // There is no view at this position, we create a new one. In this case
    // by inflating an xml layout.
    if (_convertView == null)
    {
        _convertView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_item_sensor, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv = (ImageView) _convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.stateImageView);
        _convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    // We recycle a View that already exists.
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) _convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _view)
        {
        // Here I should react on the click and change the database
        // entry and the image

        cursor.moveToPosition(_position);

        Log.d("onClick: position", "" + _position);

        int sensorID = cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.SENSOR_ID));

        Log.d("onClick: sensorID", "" + sensorID);

        int state = cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.STATE));

        Log.d("onClick: state", "" + state);

        if (state == 0)
        {
            dbm.updateSensorState(sensorID, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            dbm.updateSensorState(sensorID, 0);
        }

        cursor = dbm.getIOIOSensorsCursor();

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    cursor.moveToPosition(_position);

    int state = cursor.getInt(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(IOIOSensorSchema.STATE));

    if (state == 0)
    {
        holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.av_play_over_video);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.av_pause_over_video);
    }

    return _convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement in `getView` of custom adapter.

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           cursor.moveToPosition(position);
           //change image according to you
           //get ID and update values 
           //recreate your cursor 

        }
    });
```

the cursor you are using , you have to update that cursor by requery

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific? Do I have to implement the `OnClickListener` in the `getView` and change the image resource there? Maybe you could post some sample code.

Comment: Yes, but as I said before, it doesn't have customization yet. ;-)

Comment: Your suggestion is not working. For that **holder** must be final, but  that is not possible. I'll update my first post with my new code.

Comment: I guess I almost have it now (see edited code above). The only thing that isn't working properly is refreshing the `ListView` after I clicked on an `ImageView`. Any ideas how to solve this?